# Converting HTML to XML based on Its Semantics Using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

In many cases an HTML file like this:

```
<h1>Topic 1</h1>
<p>...</p>
<h2>Topic 1.1</h2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h2>Topic 1.2</h2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<h2>Topic 1.3</h2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
```

is actually semantically like this (if represented in XML):

```
<topiclevel1>
<p>...</p>

<topiclevel2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</topiclevel2>

<topiclevel2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</topiclevel2>

<topiclevel2>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
</topiclevel2>

</topiclevel1>
```

Is there a standardized way to convert from the former to the latter. Specifically, are there any PHP libraries that do this?

Comment: Why is the HTML not using `<section>`s?

Comment: The way the HTML is formatted is not up to me

Comment: There is no standardised way (too specific a case) and no libraries to do this out of the box. Nevertheless, there are some core libraries to handle XML: DOMDocument, SimpleXML, and XMLReader/XMLWriter. But the logic is up to you.